# Open Specific MailItem in Outlook from C# via Mail.EntryID

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Similar to this question, 
[Open Specific MailItem in Outlook from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931757/open-specific-mailitem-in-outlook-from-c-sharp) , In a C# VSTO application I'm trying to open an email in a new outlook window/inspector using the method **GetFolderFromID** and passing it's **EntryID** and **StoreID**.

Full code below:

```
Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder mySentBox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);                
Outlook.MailItem myMail = ((Outlook.MailItem)mySentBox.Items[1]);
string guid = myMail.EntryID;
string folderStoreID = mySentBox.StoreID;
Outlook.MailItem getItem = (Outlook.MailItem)mapiNameSpace.GetItemFromID(guid, folderStoreID);
getItem.Display();
```

The below code only opens up the requested email in a new window when the email is already selected within outlook.

```
getItem.Display();
```

If not selected, the following error returns.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComException: 'A dialog box is open. Close it and try again'.
```

I've also attempted adding a new inspector & activating/displaying the email object via it with no success.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error simply means a dialog box is open. Make sure there are no **modal** windows displayed and make sure you never call `MailItem.Display(true`) to display items modally.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, it seems that instead of calling the existing Outlook.Application, I was creating a new one which then caused the issue with modality.

Comment: Outlook is a singleton - you cannot start more than one instance of outlook.exe in the same Windows user context.